# Trying to upload image with angular 9 - formData send empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I tried to send image file to server , FormData send empty object ... When I console.log it shows as empty.
this my code :

```
public addProduct(product: any) {
    const myForm:FormData = new FormData();
    myForm.append('image', product.img);
    myForm.append('product', JSON.stringify(product));
    console.log(myForm);
    return this.http.post<any>(this.myApi + 'add-product', myForm);
  }
```

Comment: what is product.img?

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(myForm)` will always print an empty object like structure of type FormData, in order to see the values you need to use the `get` method.

```
const myForm = new FormData();

myForm.append('image', 'myImage');
myForm.append('product', 'myProduct');

console.log(myForm.get('image')); // myImage
console.log(myForm.get('product')); // myProduct
```

Answer (score 0):

i forgot on server side install express-fileupload
on Client side everything is ok..

Comment: close this question then.